# Optional validation rule in FluentValidation

Tags: c#, validation, nhibernate, fluentvalidation

I have got two different models which extend an basemodel.

```
public class basemodel 
{
   public string prename;
   public string surname;
}

public class modelA : basemodel 
{
   public string street;
   public int gender; //0 = m / 1 = f
}

public class modelB : basemodel 
{
   public string street; 
}
```

Now I wanna validate them in my HTTP PUT controller. The controller decides between the `modelA` or `modelB` depending on the role a user has (admin can see `modelA` and user can see `modelB`).

```
public ActionResult Put(MyDto myDto)
{
   if (validationSrv.IsValid(myDto, ruleSetNames: "Edit", propertyNames: null))
   {
       session.Merge(myDto);
       session.Flush();
       session.Evict(myDto);
   } //else xyz
}
```

My actual validator looks like this.

```
public MyValidator() : AbstractValidator<basemodel>
{
   RuleSet("Edit", () =>
   {
       editBaseValidation();
   });
}

private void editBaseValidation()
{
   RuleFor(a => a.prename)
        .NotEmpty()
        .Length(5, 50);

   RuleFor(a => a.surname)
        .NotEmpty()
        .Length(5, 50);

   //say this is optional!
   RuleFor(a => a.street)
        .NotEmpty()

   //say this is optional!
   RuleFor(a => a.gender)
        .NotEmpty()
}
```

Now my question. Is there a way to say my validator that some attributes like `street` or `gender` are optional depending on the models used? So I can use only the validator for the basemodel and the validator decides which attribures to validate or not.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to do this in another way. I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1 so [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1) is what I've found.